# $\int_{|z|=\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\sin z}{1 + z + z ^2 + ... + z^n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How Can I prove that the following integral is $0$ using Residue?

$$I =\int_{|z|=\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\sin z}{1 + z + z ^2 + ... + z^n}$$

We have :

$$I=   \int_{|z|=\frac{1}{2}} \frac{(1-z) \sin z}{1 
 -z^{n+1}}$$

Thank you...

Comment: There's no pole inside the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lord Shark the Unknown delivers the punchline: the contour does not contain any poles. Details follow.

Your second form shows that poles are going to be where
$$
1 - z^{n+1} = 0
$$
with the mild assumption that $n$ is a positive integer.

These poles all lie on the unit circle $\lvert z \rvert = 1$. The contour specified in the problem is inside of the unit circle. Therefore, no poles are enclosed.

This is the resolution where $n=3$:

[image: contour]